# How do I import a Python lambda layer?

Tags: python, import, aws-lambda

I have a file with this as the contents.

```
def print_hello_world():
    print ('Hello World')
```

It's zipped up in a folder with a `__init__.py` file.

I add this as the layer and set the correct runtime of python3.6.

How do import it into my lambda function via lambda code?

Edit: After researching I found that lambda mounts the layers at /opt and if you add /opt to your syspath via sys.path.insert(0, '/opt') then you can import your layers.

You can see your layers at: print(os.listdir("/opt"))

There's gotta be a more elegant way to do this!

Comment: Check [here](https://medium.com/@adhorn/getting-started-with-aws-lambda-layers-for-python-6e10b1f9a5d) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html).

Comment: Saw both of those. The AWS docs are 100% cli based. The article was just wrong(to put it bluntly).

Comment: I'm using cloudformation.  I found that adding sys.path.insert(0, '/opt') allows me to import my layers.  After identifying the location of my layer with print(os.listdir("/opt")).

Comment: There's gotta be a better way though right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

You must to allocate all the packages you install with pip install ... into a zip file that ends with the folllowing file structure:

```
[your zip file].zip
|_python/
  |_all.../
  |_your.../
  |_packages, modules.../
```

Another boring way is:

```
[your zip file].zip
|_python/
  |_lib/
    |_python3.x/
      |_site-packages/
        |_all.../
        |_your.../
        |_packages, modules.../
```

with this structure you lambda code get the modules you have.

I hope this make done your issue.

Answer (score 11):

So I've recently ran into this issue, and I believe I found a cleaner way to import your layers.

First for the structure of the zip file which you upload:

- You do not need an `__init__.py` file
- Put all the scripts which you want to import into a folder name `python`
- Zip up that python folder (choose any name you want) and upload it to your layer
- Once uploaded, and the layer has been configured in your lambda function, you can simply use it with `import {filename}`

So if your script in the `python` folder was called something like `custom_helper.py`, import it in your lambda with `import custom_helper`.

I am not sure if this is the **clean** way to do it, but it seems simple enough to start.

Answer (score 7):

Your zip file should have the following structure:

**python/lib/python3.7/site-packages**

That is, it needs a folder named Python, and within that a folder named lib, and within that a folder named python3.7, and within that a folder named site-packages. Anything inside that folder will be available for import.

(If you're using another version of Python, that version should be in the path instead of 3.7)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to:

1. Build you lambda layer using Docker:
   `sudo docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-${penv}" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/${penv}/site-packages/; exit"`
2. Upload layer to AWS
3. Add layer to your lambda
4. Modity `sys.path` in your Lambda before import

```
    import sys; 
    sys.path.append('/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages');
    import apsw
    print(apsw.__file__)

/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apsw.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

**Update:**
It looks like you need to place build under /opt/python so you can use it without
`sys.path.append('/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages');`

### New build steps:

```
mkdir -vp my-layer/python && cd my-layer/python
python3 -m pip install click -t ./ 
cd ..
zip -r9 my-layer python
```

now add layer to lambda function
and you can import:

```
import click
```