# Add lambda layer for custom package

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I created a custom python package to use different lambda functions from time to time. How I create a zip file to add it as a lambda layer? The examples I saw for the custom package are deployed with a specific function but I will use this package with different functions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read the answer of @Cecaro : [How do I import a Python lambda layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54420077)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can try to add an lambda layer one is to create a custom layer of your package using AWS CLI or you can manually create using create layer functionality provided bs AWS. Another one is to use AWS CLI command which is :-

aws lambda publish-layer-version
--layer-name "name of layer" 
--description "description you want to add"  \
--license-info "MIT" 
--content S3Bucket="name of s3 bucket", S3Key="zip folder path" 
--compatible-runtimes "runtime for layer"
--compatible-architectures "architecture of the lambda function"

Note - Please take care that the architecture should be compatible with the binary files of the package otherwise the layer won't work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).